# Play framework scala and mysql error

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, anorm

I have play framework(scala) working with mysql on my os ubuntu

I have example  code

```
  val computers = SQL(
    """
      select * FROM 'computer'
      where 'computer.tytul' like {filter}
      order by {orderBy} nulls last
      limit {pageSize} offset {offset}
    """
  ).on(
    'pageSize -> pageSize, 
    'offset -> offest,
    'filter -> filter,
    'orderBy -> orderBy
  ).as(Computer.withCompany *)
```

That yields the following error when I use it with MySQL

> [MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ''computer' where 'computer.tytul' like '%%'
>   order by 2 nulls' at line 1]

That code was working with database in memory!
Can somebody help?

Comment: You need to use backticks ` instead of apostrophes ' for the table and column names.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would work if you removed the quotes altogether (or use backticks, as suggested by Carsten).

---

Here is the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: I go ahed (`` is good), but i have another problem 
example error `[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`computer_seq`), 'test','test2','2012-09-09 00:00:00','test2',55,11 ' at line 1]`

When i try to inster data

Insert query           insert into `computer` values (
            (select next value for `computer_seq`), 
          {tytul},{autor},{data},{opinia},{ocena},{stron}
          )

Comment: @user2692684 If your table has the ID column defined with AUTO_INCREMENT (which it probably should), just pass `NULL` in the values:
`values ( NULL, {tytul},{autor},{data},{opinia},{ocena},{stron} )`